# Background not displayed for the Navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a navigation drawer, thanks to the sample available with the sdk.

I changed the navigation drawer background to an image of mine. It works well on my phone (Samsung Ace 3 Android 4.2.2), on a nexus 4 with lollipop. But on a
friend's phone (HTC Sense, with lollipop) the navigation drawer has no background.

You can see that :
[image]

And here is what is expected:

[image]

The background is set in the layout xml file, as follows :

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/navigation_drawer_background"
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:divider="@null"
   android:dividerHeight="0dp"
   tools:context="cartel.mines.nantes2015.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

It seems to be a problem of overlay. Overlays are very annoying!

Comment: do you have have your background layout file in your all drawable folders like mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi

Comment: I just tried to change this, and to put the drawable in every drawable folders. It worked fine. What I don't understand, is that it is not supposed to be a problem, it worked on my phone, and as it is said here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038435/what-if-image-is-not-found-in-drawable-ldpi.
I will post the answer, in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: if you want i can post the answer and you can accept it

Comment: If you want, I will accept it.

Comment: You had to set background to your custom layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing your background drawable file from different drawable folders according to screen density.Create images with proper resolution which you want for the different screen resolutions and place it into respective folder(mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi or xxhdpi).

Comment: Even if I thought it shouldn't be a problem, that was the answer to my issue. Many thanks !

Comment: This was my problem as well. Thank you! Could also you enlighten me on how to resize to mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. Does AS do it automatically? Or do I have to go through each one, resize, and put them in their respective folders? What dimensions are each one? Thanks!

Comment: @ONE: you need to resize it and then put them in their respective folders.